# Receiving unspecified error relating to 'SELECT INTO'

Tags: oracle10g

Receiving the error message:
ERROR at line 6: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored 0.03 seconds

There are no errors relating to the creation of the database itself, the tables involved or any of the insert statements.

Any suggestions appreciated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Function1(NumberOfBugs NUMBER, TotalIncome FLOAT)

    RETURN FLOAT

    IS PricePerBug FLOAT;

    BEGIN
        SELECT INTO TotalIncome SUM(ProjectValue) FROM tblProject;
        SELECT INTO NumberOfBugs COUNT(idBug) FROM tblBug;
        PricePerBug := (NumberOfBugs)/(TotalIncome);
        RETURN PricePerBug;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No data found, no result to display; exception handled...');
        WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
        RETURN 'Too many rows returned...';
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20015, 'Unknown exception in function Function1.');
        RETURN PricePerBug;

    END Function1;
    /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Select Into statement like :

```
Select [ColumnName1],[ColumnName2]
Into Table Name
From table Name
Where Your conditions
```

Are you following this syntax ? Please verify

Comment: You would think that I would seeing as I used that syntax for five previous procedures before the function.  Looking at the same code for too long!  Thankyou.